# Python, hiding password in the shell

Tags: python, passwords

Is there a way I can hide a password in python shell?, like showing dots. This is for an input for a login in a python program.
`getpass` shows this:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
 File "C:\Python34\lib\getpass.py", line 101   
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)   
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed. Enter your password: hammad
hammad
```

The password is visible, and I have my own python script for getting a user name and then the password, using a database to check if account exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually utilise the library `getpass` as follows:

```
import getpass

password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
print(password)
```

A general rule of thumb is to not show the number of characters in a person's password via the asterisks/dots shown, which is what `getpass` does.

Answer (score 1):

there is the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html?highlight=getpass#getpass.getpass) module. that hides input (but does not show dots or anything).

Comment: Can the dots / asterisks be added somehow?

Comment: @CIsForCookies `getpass` can't do that (as it seems to be hard to do that cross-platform). on *nix you could use [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#user-input). but security-wise this is not a good idea: you are giving away the password-length.

Answer (score 0):

this getpass module only shows password when using in IDLE. but when you run script in cmd it will not
you can do this by double clicking the .py file and not opening it with IDLE
or you can do is open cmd and write.

> c:\Python27\python.exe 'filepath'.py
>   this statement may change according to where your python forlder is installer of or which version you are using but the syntax remain same
>   \python.exe 'filepath'.py